# How can I generate a list of sequential numbers, one per line?

Tags: line-numbers, text-generation

Starting from a blank slate, how can I obtain a document that contains

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
…
100
```

To be clear, I don't want these numbers displayed in the margin; I want them inserted into the document itself.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use `:put` and `range()`:

```
:put =range(1,100)
```

To avoid the blank line at the top ([kudos to romainl](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12/how-can-i-generate-a-list-of-sequential-numbers-one-per-line#comment15_14)), use `:0put`:

```
:0put =range(1,100)
```

Comment: Or in insert mode with `<C-r>=range(1,100)`.

Answer (score 20):

In addition to Undo's pure-vim `:put =range(1,100)` (which actually leaves you with a blank line up top), you can, depending on your OS, use one of its commands. E.g., on a Unix/Linux box:

```
%!seq 1 100
```

The above works by piping the entire (empty) buffer to `seq`, which ignores its input and just outputs the numbers 1 to 100. Vim then replaces the entire buffer with `seq`'s output.

That's useful when you're already familiar with some command-line way to get what you want.

Comment: This "unasks" the question which is why I think it is better than the accepted one. Yes, you can make vim do the job, just as you can use a crescent wrench to stir soup. Vim is a text editor, not an arbitrary text generator; there are much more obvious tools for that.

Answer (score 18):

For the record, and definitely not the shortest way (see @Undo's awesome solution),
but sequence of keystrokes will do it too:

<kbd>i</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

Let me break that down for you:

1. `i1<Esc>` -- insert the number 1, then get back out to command mode
2. `qa` -- start recording a macro in register "a"
3. `Y` -- copy the current line
4. `p` -- paste the current line (cursor will also move to the pasted line)
5. `<Ctrl>a` -- increment the next number on the line, making it 2
6. `q` -- stop recording the macro (was register "a")
7. `98@a` -- replay the macro in register "a" 98 times

Answer (score 8):

Here is a different approach, that needs a newer Vim (something like 7.4.800)

This assumes an empty buffer and '1' in register a.
First enter 100 1 into your buffer, <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

Then visually select lines 2 till 100 <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

Now press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Read the help at `:h v_g_CTRL-A`

Comment: You have to add let @a="1" in your answer. Beginners might get stuck up to find how to store value 1 in register a.

Comment: I have seen the gCtrl+A combo in other similar solutions. However I have been unable to find an explanation of what it is doing/how it works? Do you have a reference in the documentation that explains what g does? Thanks! If I find an explanation I will post it.

Comment: documentation is at `:h g_CTRL-A`

Comment: I had missed the link to the v_g_CTRL-A section.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is really old, but there's another way you can do it also. Try this:

```
99o<esc>:%s/^/\=line('.')<cr>
```

`99o<esc>` will just open up 100 blank lines. Then, we run a substitute command:

```
:%                  " On every line
  s/                " substitute
    ^/              " the start of the line. (This will always match no matter what)
      \=            " Evaluate:
        line('.')   " The current line.
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me find: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_an_expression_in_substitute_command, which provides more details. +1