# Insert a string of sequential numbers in one line

Tags: command-line

Consider I work on a file like this:

```
'90008000','90008005'
```

How can I insert the following text after `'90008000',` in Vim:

```
'90008001','90008002','90008003','90008004',
```

I have read [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12/how-can-i-generate-a-list-of-sequential-numbers-one-per-line), but I do not know how to insert these numbers in the same line.

Comment: You could use a strategy: split lines first, use that solution, than join all lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a macro. Starting with the cursor on the first character of the line, type `qqyf,P<C-a>F'q3@q`:

```
qq      "start the macro recording to register `q`
yf,     "yank the part you are looking to duplicate,
P       "paste it *before* the cursor.
<C-a>   "increment the next number by one
F'      "move backwards until '
q       "stop recording the macro,
3@q     "execute previously recorded macro 3 times.
```

In practice, it is often easier to do this kind of things linewise and join the lines afterward. `:join!` can be used to avoid spaces while joining the lines.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I'd probably just do this manually using regular insert/motion operations, `y`, `p`, and `<c-a>`, but you *could* do this by recording and replaying a macro with the following keystrokes:

```
0qqt,ya';a,<c-r>"<esc>h<c-a>q3@q
```

Broken down:

1. `0`: Move to the start of the line,
2. `qq`: Start recording a macro,
3. `t,`: Jump "till" the first comma,
4. `ya'`: Yank the number and the surrounding quotes,
5. `;`: Jump "till" the comma again,
6. `a,<c-r>"<esc>`: Insert a new comma, and the text you yanked previously,
7. `h<c-a>`: Increment the number,
8. `q`: Stop recording the macro,
9. `3@q`: Replay the macro 3 times to add the next three numbers.

There are certainly other ways to achieve this with a macro: this is just the first that sprung to mind.

Macros are an incredibly powerful tool once you've got your head around how to order operations in a way such that repeating them will produce the desired results.

When you first start using them it might take you a couple of tries or more to figure out a working macro (`u` is your friend!), but after a while you can pretty much get it right on the first go every time, without having to think too much about how to do it. Remember that *everything* you type is recorded, so minor editing mistakes in recording can easily be corrected just as you would do so normally.

Relevant help topics:

```
:help complex-repeat
:help CTRL-A
:help registers
:help i_CTRL-R
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of similar lines, here is a mapping that could help you:

```
nnoremap <silent> ,x :let [a, b] = map(split(getline('.'), ','), 'eval(v:val)') <bar> execute "s/^.*$/'" . join(range(a,b), "','") . "'"<CR>
```

Hit `,x` on a line following the form `'a','b'` (with a < b), and it should be converted into:
 `'a','a+1','a+2',...,'b'`.

---

The mapping executes 2 Ex commands separated by a pipe symbol (`<bar>`).

The 1st command stores the 2 numbers on the line in the variables `a` and `b`.

```
:let [a, b] = map(split(getline('.'), ','), 'eval(v:val)')
```

It can be broken down like this:

```
getline('.')    returns the current line

split(g, ',')   splits the string g where a comma is found
                example: split('1,2,3', ',') returns [1, 2, 3]

                here g stands for: getline('.')

map(s, 'eval(v:val)')
                s being a list, map() takes each of its item and transforms it with
                the operation: eval(v:val)
                where v:val is an item of s
                example: map(['1', '2', '3'], 'eval(v:val)') returns [1, 2, 3]

                eval() evaluates a string; useful to get a number inside quotes
                example: eval('123') returns 123

                here s stands for: split(getline('.'), ',')

let [a, b] = map(s, 'eval(v:val)')
                stores in the variables a and b the 2 items inside the list returned
                by the map() function
```

The 2nd command substitutes the current line with a new one, containing the missing numbers between `a` and `b`.

```
execute "s/^.*$/'" . join(range(a,b), "','") . "'"
```

It can be broken down like this:

```
range(a,b)      returns the list of numbers between a and b
                example: range(1,3) returns [1, 2, 3]

join(r, "','")  returns a string which concatenates all the items from the list r
                separated by the 3 characters ','
                example: join([1, 2, 3], "','") returns "1','2','3"

                here r stands for: range(a,b)

execute "s/^.*$/'" . j . "'"

                executes the Ex command resulting from the concatenation of 3 strings:
                "s/^.*$/'"
                j 
                "'"

                The resulting Ex command is a substitution command (:s/^.*$/'j')
                which substitutes the whole line (^.*$) with the string "'j'"

                here j stands for: join(range(a,b), "','")
```